# Where should I put my input files that should be accessible from anywhere?

Tags: miktex, input, texmf

I'm using MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter to compile my projects.
Is there a folder where I can store all your input files which I want to include in another document, so I don't have to put all the files in the specific folder where my current document is located?

Comment: Search for texmf local folder. Maybe this: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html

Comment: You can define your own class or style file that loads the required packages and input files. You define the class/package once and use it several times.